# what obj files can be added to nglview?

Tags: iphone, xcode, 3d

I am making an iphone app according to this tutorial http://www.icodeblog.com/2012/09/07/3856/ however, when trying to replace the 3d obj(earth) with some obj file of mine, it does not work, is there any specific requirements for the obj file added to `nglview`?
This is the viewdidload part:

```
    NGLView *tmpView = [[NGLView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 110, 140, 140)];
// Set its delegate to self so the drawview method is used.

    tmpView.delegate = self;
// Add the new view on top of our existing view. 

    [self.view addSubview:tmpView];
    tmpView.contentScaleFactor = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
    // Setup some initial environment states to be applied to our mesh.
   NSDictionary *settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
              kNGLMeshOriginalYes, kNGLMeshKeyOriginal,
              @"1", kNGLMeshKeyNormalize, nil];

// Initialize the mesh which includes the model file to import (.obj or .dae).

_mesh = [[NGLMesh alloc] initWithFile:@"PAN.obj" settings:settings delegate:nil];

// Initialize the camera used to render the scene.
_camera = [[NGLCamera alloc] initWithMeshes:_mesh, nil];

// If a trasparent background of the NGLView is needed
   tmpView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
   nglGlobalColorFormat(NGLColorFormatRGBA);
   nglGlobalFlush();
```

Comment: Can you edit your question using proper error log? I guess you might not include some required frameworks in your XCode build.

Comment: actually, there is no error, just showing me nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nglview` is a part of **[NinevehGL](http://nineveh.gl)** framework .

`NinevehGL` is a 3D engine forged with pure Obj-C

Here is the [community forum for beginners](http://nineveh.gl/community/forum/beginners)

You can find the basic lessons [here](http://nineveh.gl/docs/tutorials/)

Comment: there you go,and the obj file is downloaded from the internet, a normal one

Comment: I have only got hotmail.  luzegg012@hotmail.com   Thank you a lot!

Comment: I have sent now.. please find the file and update me the result

Comment: I have downloaded files from http://groups.csail.mit.edu/graphics/classes/6.837/F03/models/

Comment: Error while processing NGLParserOBJ with file "m4.obj".
At line 0.
The WaveFront Object file was not found in the specified path.
The path to the OBJ file should reflect its real location, if only the file's name was specified, the search will be executed in the global path.
For more information check the nglGlobalFilePath() function.

I place my obj in the same file as your obj...